# How to get programmatically Graph API methods

Tags: facebook-graph-api, reflection, methods

Does the Facebook Graph API offer [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) like [the Flickr API](http://flickr.com/services/api/flickr.reflection.getMethodInfo.htm)?

For example, Flickr provides the following reflective information about the `flickr.urls.lookupUser` method:

```
{ "method": { "name": "flickr.urls.lookupUser", "needslogin": 0, "needssigning": 0, "requiredperms": 0, 
    "description": { "_content": "Returns a user NSID, given the url to a user's photos or profile." }, 
    "response": { "_content": "<user id=\"12037949632@N01\">\r\n    <username>Stewart<\/username> \r\n<\/user>" } }, "arguments": { 
    "argument": [
      { "name": "api_key", "optional": 0, "_content": "Your API application key. <a href=\"\/services\/api\/misc.api_keys.html\">See here<\/a> for more details." },
      { "name": "url", "optional": 0, "_content": "The url to the user's profile or photos page." }
    ] }...
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  It's in the documentation for the Graph API.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question. They are asking for reflection like that provided by the Flickr API (see https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.reflection.getMethodInfo.htm). Reflection could be used in many ways e.g. in an API wrapper to provide interactive help, implementation via code generation, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing there is to getting the documenation programmtically is to use the `metadata=1` parameter in the call. This will return a `metadata` object with `connections` that the object has (aka - additional endpoints), along the description of its `fields`

[Here is an example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?path=me?metadata=1&token=%3Ctoken%3E&method=GET):

```
GET /me?metadata=1
```